# Handle server errors in SailsJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, error-handling, sails.js, node-webkit

I am creating an application in SailsJS. I am getting errors, like, typeError or 500 errors when some error occurs in DB related queries.I am using MongoDB. Is there any way that I can catch this error in server-side.

Now, these errors are crashing my server. And the server stops. I have to restart the server again.

Please help me in fixing this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely waterline is throwing an exception and you're not catching it. Here's some code to fix that:

```
controlleAction:function(req,res){
  var invalidParams = {};//whatever's causing the error

  Model
  .create(invalidParams)
  .exec(function(err,created){
    if(err) res.json(err);
    res.json(created);
  });
}
```

you could also use the promise syntax

```
controlleAction:function(req,res){
  var invalidParams = {};//whatever's causing the error

  Model
  .create(invalidParams)
  .then(function(created){
    res.json(created);
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    res.json(err);
  });
}
```

If you're trying to catch every global error in your entire application,
in your app.js, there's a line like this:

```
// Start server
sails.lift(rc('sails'));
```

surround that line with a try catch block like so:

```
try{
  // Start server
  sails.lift(rc('sails'));
}catch(e){
  console.dir(e);
}
```

Comment: I have given the same code. That is working actually. But I would like to know if there is any generic method to handle all the errors that is thrown from the server. Like if the model doesn't exists in the DB or some code has gone wrong, the server will stop running. Can I somehow catch those errors which are thrown?

Comment: I tried this one. it's working. But no response is sent to front-end. it's showing loading. Can I get the request and response object here?

Answer (score 1):

Please be careful there:

```
controlleAction:function(req,res){
  var invalidParams = {};//whatever's causing the error

  Model
  .create(invalidParams)
  .exec(function(err,created){
    // return res.json()
    if(err) return res.json(err);
    return res.json(created);
  });
}
// The difference is in the return
if(err) return res.json(err);
```

If you have an error, without the return, the server will crash because it would try to send two responses one with the error and another one with the created object.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sails 0.10.x you can pass errors to next handler:

```
controlleAction:function(req,res, next){
 var invalidParams = {};//whatever's causing the error

 Model
  .create(invalidParams)
  .exec(function(err,created){
    if(err) return next(err);
    return res.json(created);
  });
}
```

And then process errors in ["Custom Responses"](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Custom-Responses)

Comment: If i try this method, i should give it in all my services and controllers right? Can i get some method like in app,js wherein i can give just one handler.

Comment: If you have error in callback as a result of async action you should pass it somewhere to process ("next" in this case) and if you have "synchronous" error as a result of "throw" it will be passed to "serverError" response.